# regular expression to match either or 2 patterns

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match all parenthesis or quotes AND/OR the pattern `##.*##` (so I can remove them all in 1 call). I thought `[\(\)\"]* | ##.*##` would do the trick. RegExp tester says

```
[\(\)\"]* | ##.*##
/
gm
1st Alternative [\(\)\"]* 
Match a single character present in the list below [\(\)\"]*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\( matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
\) matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)
\" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
  matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
2nd Alternative  ##.*##
 ## matches the characters  ## literally (case sensitive)
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
## matches the characters ## literally (case sensitive)
```

which also looks like it should work, but given strings like

- `(`
- `()`
- `""`
- `##VAL##`
- `" ##XXX## ) "

NOTHING matches. Each of the patterns on their own match the corresponding strings, but when I put them together, not so much. I'm guessing it's got to be my `|` operator, but that's where I get in a little over my head.

Can anyone shed some light for me? Thx!!

Comment: `[()"]+|##.*?##`?

Comment: as said in the RegExp tester:   matches the character   literally (case sensitive)

Comment: The question is why it doesn't work right? It's not how to combine regex. Which there really is no such thing or method, so being a duplicate of something without an answer is ridiculous @ WiktorStribiżew.

Comment: The reason _your_ regex doesn't work is that `[\(\)\"]*` will be matched _every single time_ and this `##.*##` will _never_ be matched. When any item in an alternation is optional `*` and is _first_, the match will be satisfied with nothing as well as what's in the class if it finds that. When _nothing_ is matched, all engines increment the current position  for the next match, until it iteratively reaches the end of the string. The fix is to make it _non-optional_ with a `+`